# Will a foreignkey link my two tables in this example?

Tags: django, django-models

latest_entries is a list of items for sale and I am trying to display the sellers reviewaverage with each listing.  The problem is, the field 'reviewavg' is in 'MyProfile' model, so I'm not sure if a change should be made to my models, views or the template in order to display the sellers review average along with each listing.  I realize I could just make a reviewavg field in the Entry model, but that does not seem the most efficient way to do this.

If it helps, you can see the logic I am attempting here down in my template.html (bottom line).  Will using a foreignkey allow me to I access the 'reviewavg' field in the for loop below?  Better yet, what is the proper way to do this?

```
#models.py
class MyProfile(UserenaBaseProfile):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,
                                unique=True,
                                verbose_name=_('user'),
                                related_name='my_profile')
    reviewavg=models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=5)
    coverpic = models.ImageField(upload_to="site_media/media/covers/", null=True, blank=True)

class Entry(models.Model):
    headline= models.CharField(max_length=200,)
    body_text = models.TextField()
    author=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='entryauthors')
    pub_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    zipcode =models.IntegerField(null=True, max_length=10)
    entrytype = models.IntegerField(null=True, max_length=3)
    price1 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    price2 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    price3 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    price4 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    price5 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    item_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to="site_media/media/items/")


#views.py
def storefront(request):
    latest_entries = Entry.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:16]
    context = {'latest_entries': latest_entries}

#template.html
{% for i in latest_entries %}
    {{ i.headline }}
    {{ i.price1 }}   
    {{ i.body_text }}
    {{ i.author }}
    {{ i.author.reviewavg }}  //not working
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: what is the actual value of settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL???

Comment: I'm not sure, how would I find that out? just print it in the console?

Comment: the default value for settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL is auth.User, if you haven't specifically changed it (by asigning a different value to this setting in your settings file) it probably has that value. But you can debug your project and inspect its value, or print it to the console, just to be sure.

Comment: If it is auth.User can I accesss the avgreview from it?

Comment: sure, just do: i.author.my_profile.reviewavg. It should work

Comment: I'll give it a shot when I get home and report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seams to be that i.author is a foreing key to auth.User, not MyProfile.
Try i.author.my_profile.reviewavg

Comment: That worked.  This might be dumb question but why 'my_profile' and not 'MyProfile'? My model is named MyProfile, I don't know what 'my_profile' refers to.

Comment: In your MyProfile model, while declaring the user field, you gave it a 'related_name' of "my_profile". That means that when you want to access the MyProfile instance from the related User instance (navigate the relationship in the opposite direction) you must use that name ("my_profile").